# NullPointerException on selectedImageView.getDrawable()?

Tags: android, gridview, imageview, drawable

I'm new to android, and I am getting a NullPointerException on the line with the if statement in this code, and I am not sure why. This code is in my onItemClick method for my gridview in which I stored a 2d array of ImageViews.

```
            ImageView selected = (ImageView) grid.getSelectedView();

            if(selected.getDrawable().equals(R.drawable.piecered2))
            {
                Toast.makeText(game.this, "red" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

The app runs, but when I actually click on an item, it crashes, giving me a NullPointerException.

Comment: plz paste the errorlog

Answer (score 1):

The documentation states `Return the view's drawable, or null if no drawable has been assigned.`.
Do you have a drawable assigned? If not, you are calling the `equals` method of null within the if clause, which then causes the NullPointerException.
If you are sure, you have a drawale assigned, we could need more code here.

Answer (score 1):

Putting aside your `NullPointerException`, the way you compare the things are wrong. Because `.equals()` method is used to compare the strings. Your R.drawable.piecered2 returns an integer value(id) which is generated in R.java.  Your `getDrawable()` returns a `Drawable` object which can't be compared with an integer.

Coming to your `NPE issue`, clearly log the values of `getDrawable()` before you actually make use of them whether it contains null or the most convenient way to track these is to debug your code.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have only `ImageView` in your `GridView`.

```
View v = grid.getChildAt(0);

if(v instanceof ImageView)
{
   ImageView selected = (ImageView) v;

   if(selected.getDrawable().equals(R.drawable.piecered2))
      {
         Toast.makeText(game.this, "red" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
}
```